# The engine has retried too many times please restart

Tags: flutter, file, view

I used this example for reading files
[flutter_file_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_view/example)

I am getting this error

```
The engine has retried too many times please restart

D/com.file.view.FlutterFileViewPlugin(17529): FlutterFileView: TBS - Ready to initialize.
D/com.file.view.FlutterFileViewPlugin(17529): FlutterFileView: TBS - Start the initialization.
D/com.file.view.FlutterFileViewPlugin(17529): FlutterFileView: TBS - Current Status - START
D/com.file.view.FlutterFileViewPlugin(17529): FlutterFileView: TBS - Download completed - 127 - FAIL
```

I tried for PDFs, tex, etct files reading within the app. I expected that not coming

Answer (score 0):

The error message "The engine has retried too many times please restart" indicates that there may be an issue with the Flutter engine that requires a restart. This could be caused by a variety of factors, including a problem with the plugin you are using or an issue with your Flutter installation.

Check your network connection: Make sure that your device is connected to a stable network connection and try to download the file again.

Verify the file URL: Double-check the URL of the file you are trying to download and make sure that it is correct.

Comment: Yes brother ,What you said ,I did ,but no use ,same error is coming

Comment: if you tried that one, please help me on that , otherwise please give another suggestion for download and view files with in the flutter app with using recent flutter version(I am using for chat application)